# how to add docker name parameter into kuberntes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am deploy the xxl-job application in Kubernetes(v1.15.2), now the application deploy success but registry client service failed.If deploy it in docker, it should look like this:

```
docker run -e PARAMS="--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-service.example.com/xxl-job?Unicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8 --spring.datasource.username=root --spring.datasource.password=<mysql-password>" -p 8180:8080 -v /tmp:/data/applogs --name xxl-job-admin  -d xuxueli/xxl-job-admin:2.0.2
```

and when start application,the server side give me tips:

```
22:33:21.078 logback [http-nio-8080-exec-7] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/xxl-job-admin/api/registry] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

I am searching from project issue and find the problem may be I could not pass the project name in docker to be part of it's url, so give me this tips.The client side give this error:

```
23:19:18.262 logback [xxl-job, executor ExecutorRegistryThread] INFO   c.x.j.c.t.ExecutorRegistryThread - >>>>>>>>>>> xxl-job registry fail, registryParam:RegistryParam{registryGroup='EXECUTOR', registryKey='job-schedule-executor', registryValue='172.30.184.4:9997'}, registryResult:ReturnT [code=500, msg=xxl-rpc remoting fail, StatusCode(404) invalid. for url : http://xxl-job-service.dabai-fat.svc.cluster.local:8080/xxl-job-admin/api/registry, content=null]
```

so to solve the problem, I should execute command as possible as the same in kubernetes like execute with docker. The question is: How to pass the docker command `--name` to kubernetes environment? I have already tried this:

```
           "env": [

              {
                "name": "name",
                "value": "xxl-job-admin"
              }
            ],
```

and also tried this:

```
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "xxl-job-admin",
            "image": "xuxueli/xxl-job-admin:2.0.2",
         }
         ]
```

Both did not work.

Comment: You appear to be running a Spring Boot application. If you expect the server to answer requests to URI paths starting with that prefix, then you must configuration property `server.servlet.context-path` to `/xxl-job-admin`